# Why can't Pillow module be found?

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I've gotten the error about the fact that Pil cannot be found.

[image]

So I checked to see if it was installed

[image]

Pil is not installed.

my import statement looks like this

[image]

So I have no idea why this is happening. I installed it with pip ( obviously with pip list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say for sure what happened.. but I had tried closing idle and then reopening it and it finally worked.

I had done that previously as well after uninstalling Pillow and then installing it through easy_install. It still didn't work right after that.. but maybe closing idle after running it through easy_install made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive. Do this:

```
from PIL import Image
```